# Parking Area Definition in Veins

Tags: veins

I studied in sumo that we can define a parking area.Can we simulate the same scenario(road network with parking area) in veins as well. I want to simulate a parking area scenario in veins so is veins compatible with the parking area definition of sumo?

Comment: What do you mean by "compatible"? How would you expect your network nodes to act in this scenario?

Comment: I want my nodes to stop at parking area for some duration and then leave the area ??

Comment: Your question might be along the lines of the following then: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43700488/4707703

Answer (score 3):

When you configure SUMO XML files with a `ParkedArea`, in VEINS, vehicles will appear parked in the defined areas. In VEINS 5, you can handle whether or not a vehicle is parked using the `handleParkingUpdate()` method.

Example of configuration in SUMO XML files:

**.net.xml file:**

```
 <parkingArea id="parkingArea1" lane="D2D3_0" roadsideCapacity="1" startPos="10.00" endPos="20.00"/>
```

**.rou.xml file:**

```
    <vehicle id="0.10" depart="0.00">
        <route edges="D2D3"/>
    <stop parkingArea="parkingArea1" duration="3600.00"/>
    </vehicle>
```

**VEINS method:**

```
void MyClass::handleParkingUpdate(cObject* obj) {
    DemoBaseApplLayer::handleParkingUpdate(obj);

    //IF CAR IS PARKED
    if (mobility->getParkingState()) {
        //set color blue+red to parked cars
        findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=20,red");
        findHost()->getDisplayString().setTagArg("i", 1, "blue");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.